# pandas.dataframe.describe with text fields

Tags: python, r

While learning a combination of `R` and `pandas` for some data mining studies, I came across a disparity in how two "should be" equivalent functions behave. R's `summary(df)` works exactly as I would expect for a dataframe consisting of both number and object data (returning mean, median, quantiles, etc for the numbers, and just raw counts for the objects), which is great.

Unfortunately, pandas' `dataframe.describe()` does not work as well for string fields, instead showing a whole bunch of `NaN`s instead of the more meaningful stats that R uses. Example:

```
R                      pandas
color                  color
D: 6775         count  53940
E: 9797         unique     7
F: 9542         top        G
G:11292         freq   11292
H: 8304
I: 5422
J: 2808
```

(with the pandas' summary block containing a bunch of stats that would only be meaningful for a field with numbers in it that I have omitted for brevity).

Looking at the `describe()` help, there was nothing that looked to include this functionality. I could either completely ignore the text field, or get the bootstrapped version that it there now. I likewise could not find a different equivalent function within pandas.

Any help, or do I just have to live with this?

Note: I looked at `rpy2`, and it seems to not work well with `pandas` (or at least for my installation, for whatever reason), and I would like to avoid using it for just quick summaries.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get the same effect with `df["color"].value_counts()`

```
In [21]: series = pd.Series(list("abcdefghijklmnop"*30))
In [22]: series.value_counts()
Out[22]:
 p    30
 n    30
 o    30
 l    30
 m    30
...
```

Comment: OK, so I would just need to loop over all columns that I know are objects, either before or after using `describe()` to get the number information to replicate it. Thanks!